# what's the difference between 'defined' and 'assignment'?

Tags: python

I get a confusion...

why they have different errors?

or like JavaScript?

```
print(val1) #NameError: name 'val1' is not defined
val1 = 20


def foo1():
    print(val2)  # NameError: name 'val2' is not defined
foo1()


def foo2():
    print(val3)  # UnboundLocalError: local variable 'val3' referenced before assignment
    val3 = 20
foo2()
```

Comment: Unless you are a language lawyer, I think you can use the statements "first assignment of `val` in this scope" and "definition of `val` in this scope" interchangeably. The error itself is explained in the duplicate.

Comment: Defined means to create the human readable variable name, assignment means to give it a value. It's tricky to see the difference in python because variable types are not explicit, but in C `int size = 5;` would be defining and assigning a variable in one go and `int size; /* maybe some other code */ size = 5;` would be splitting defining a variable and assigning to it.

Answer (score 0):

Because the last one has an assignment to the value in the scope of the function and python detects that you have an assignment of value after calling the `print`.

In the second case python can not find the any definition and in the first case as you are assigning a value to in the global scope it cannot resolve that value is for the previous `val` or not (as it is not in the local scope).

Comment: OP is asking the difference between defined and assigned, not what is wrong with the code.